# How to get the number of items in a pop-up menu without opening it using applescript?

Tags: macos, automation, applescript

I want to write a script which saves the images in few formats. the thing is the formats are shown based on some condition. I means some times there will be 5 formats and sometimes 8. I want to completely automate the working of these saving things. So i decided to write an applescript. Got UI browser and using that I can access each and every pop-up menus. I'm using loops to perform save operation. The thing is I am not getting where to end. So i came up with a thought that if i can get the number of items in the pop-up menu then it will be easy for me to carry out the task.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is possible but you can't count the menu items directly. Communication is at the GUI-end and not directly to the application which means that the menu needs to appear before you can count it.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Your application"
        --we need to menu to appear first
        click pop up button 1 of window 1
        --now the menu appeared we can count the items in it
        count menu items of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of window 1
        --now hide the menu again by pressing escape
        key code 53
    end tell
end tell
```

Well counting is one way to check the menu but the other way is get all the values in it and then click the right menu item by it's name. This is, maybe not in your case, in general the best solution.

```
set menuItemToSelect to "Title of menu item I prefer to check"

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Your Application"
        tell pop up button 1 of window 1
            --Only continue if the menu item isn't already selected
            if value of it is not equal to menuItemToSelect then
                --we need to menu to appear first
                click it
                --now the menu appeared we can get the items
                set menuItemTitles to name of menu items of menu 1
                --check if the menu item exists
                if menuItemToSelect is in menuItemTitles then
                    --menu item exists; click on it
                    click menu item menuItemToSelect of menu 1
                else
                    --the menu item to select doesn't exist; hide the menu
                    key code 53
                end if
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```