# Why does the "Click row ndx . . ." statement have no effect in this Applescript?

Tags: applescript, itunes-app

The "on switchDir" routine is intended to locate each element of the path passed as "directory" and click on it so the directory path is dived through to reach the desired final output directory.

When activating the desired row with the mouse. as normal, it **must be double-clicked** to select it!

This is the code of "on switchDir" alone:

```
on switchDir(directory, appName, selectDefault, createIt)
    local compname, bootvolume
    set compname to get computer name of (system info)
    set bootvolume to get boot volume of (system info)
    if directory is equal to "~" then set directory to system attribute ("HOME")
    if directory starts with "~/" then set directory to (system attribute ("HOME")) & text 2 through -1 of (get directory)
    if not checkPathExists(directory) then
        if createIt then
            do shell script ("mkdir -p " & (POSIX path of directory))
        else
            return false
        end if
    end if
    if directory begins with "/" then
        set directory to bootvolume & (get directory)
    end if
    tell application "System Events" to tell (process "iTunes"'s front window)
        delay 1
        click pop up button 1 of group 1 -- selects the drop-down box above the directory listing
        set max to the count of menu items of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of group 1 -- number of items in the drop-down menu
        set ndx to 1
        repeat while ndx ≤ max
            if the title of group 1's pop up button 1's menu 1's menu item ndx as string is equal to compname then -- found the absolute top-level directory
                click group 1's pop up button 1's menu 1's menu item ndx - so choose it and go to next part of navigation
                exit repeat
            else -- keep looking
                set ndx to (get ndx) + 1
            end if
        end repeat
        if ndx > max then error "Never found " & compname
        set thePath to every item of my splitString(directory, "/") -- thePath equals every individual folder in the path's name in order
        repeat with dir in thePath
            set max to the (count of rows in outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1) -- max equals the number of rows in the "directory contents" list box
            log max
            set ndx to 2 -- row 1 is just the colum titles
            repeat while ndx ≤ max
                log the value of text field 1 of UI element 1 of row ndx of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1 as string
                log the value of text field 1 of UI element 1 of row ndx of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1 as string is equal to dir as string
                if the value of text field 1 of UI element 1 of row ndx of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1 as string is equal to dir as string then -- this is the row we want!
                    log "found " & dir & " at row " & ndx as string
                    select row ndx of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1 -- included to make sure the reference in the "click" statement is correct
                    click row ndx of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1 -- supposed to "click" the desired folder name to choose it and dive deeper, BUT IT DOESN'T ACTUALLY DO THAT!
                    exit repeat -- apparently never executed because the loop keeps going past finding the desired directory's name and crashes at the first blank row!
                else
                    set ndx to (get ndx) + 1
                end if
                if ndx > max then error "Never found " & dir
             end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
    error "success"
    return true
end switchDir
```

The error occurs in "on switchDir", the rest of the code is only included so that the code will execute under "Script Editor". Both the "Click row ndx . . . ." statement and the "exit repeat" statement after it are apparently never being executed as the loop continues to run past the logging of "found ". . . . and consequently crashes on the first blank row in the list box. The found (with the quotes) can be used as a search term to find the code.

The complete, runnable application code follows:

```
on splitString(theString, theDelimiter)
    set oldDelimiters to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theDelimiter
    set theArray to every text item of theString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelimiters
    return theArray
end splitString

on checkPathExists(thePath)
    if thePath is equal to "~" then set thePath to system attribute ("HOME")
    if thePath starts with "~/" then set thePath to (system attribute ("HOME")) & text 2 through -1 of (get thePath)
    try
        POSIX file thePath as alias
        return true
    on error
        return false
    end try
end checkPathExists

on switchDir(directory, appName, selectDefault, createIt)
    local compname, bootvolume
    set compname to get computer name of (system info)
    set bootvolume to get boot volume of (system info)
    if directory is equal to "~" then set directory to system attribute ("HOME")
    if directory starts with "~/" then set directory to (system attribute ("HOME")) & text 2 through -1 of (get directory)
    if not checkPathExists(directory) then
        if createIt then
            do shell script ("mkdir -p " & (POSIX path of directory))
        else
            return false
        end if
    end if
    if directory begins with "/" then
        set directory to bootvolume & (get directory)
    end if
    tell application "System Events" to tell (process "iTunes"'s front window)
        delay 1
        click pop up button 1 of group 1 -- selects the drop-down box above the directory listing
        set max to the count of menu items of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of group 1 -- number of items in the drop-down menu
        set ndx to 1
        repeat while ndx ≤ max
            if the title of group 1's pop up button 1's menu 1's menu item ndx as string is equal to compname then -- found the absolute top-level directory
                click group 1's pop up button 1's menu 1's menu item ndx - so choose it and go to next part of navigation
                exit repeat
            else -- keep looking
                set ndx to (get ndx) + 1
            end if
        end repeat
        if ndx > max then error "Never found " & compname
        set thePath to every item of my splitString(directory, "/") -- thePath equals every individual folder in the path's name in order
        repeat with dir in thePath
            set max to the (count of rows in outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1) -- max equals the number of rows in the "directory contents" list box
            log max
            set ndx to 2 -- row 1 is just the colum titles
            repeat while ndx ≤ max
                log the value of text field 1 of UI element 1 of row ndx of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1 as string
                log the value of text field 1 of UI element 1 of row ndx of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1 as string is equal to dir as string
                if the value of text field 1 of UI element 1 of row ndx of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1 as string is equal to dir as string then -- this is the row we want!
                    log "found " & dir & " at row " & ndx as string
                    select row ndx of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1 -- included to make sure the reference in the "click" statement is correct
                    click row ndx of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1 -- supposed to "click" the desired folder name to choose it and dive deeper, BUT IT DOESN'T ACTUALLY DO THAT!
                    exit repeat -- apparently never executed because the loop keeps going past finding the desired directory's name and crashes at the first blank row!
                else
                    set ndx to (get ndx) + 1
                end if
                if ndx > max then error "Never found " & dir
             end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
    error "success"
    return true
end switchDir

set directory to "/Users/bryandunphy/Music"
try
    tell application "iTunes" to quit
end try
tell application "System Events"
    key down option
    tell application "iTunes" to activate
    key up option
    repeat until process "iTunes" exists
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
    click process "iTunes"'s window 1's button 2
    my switchDir(directory, "iTunes", false, true)
    delay 2
    set libraryName to value of text field "Save As:" of window "New iTunes Library" of process "iTunes"
    delay 2
    click process "iTunes"'s window "New iTunes Library"'s button "Save"
end tell
return libraryName
```

Any idea of the cause of the error and / or how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is pretty dense, and I doubt anyone will want to run it on their machine to test it out for fear of messing up their iTunes library. What are you trying to achieve by clicking the row? You're saying the `log "found"` and `select row` statements above the `click` work, but `click` and `exit repeat` are not respected? For starters, I don't think you need the `as string` portion of `log "found " & dir & " at row " & ndx as string`. You're already concatenating a string.

Comment: @pipwerks The "click" has no effect and the exit repeat doesn't either as the loop errors out upon trying to access the first empty row.

Comment: Yes, but what are you trying to achieve by clicking the row? It's not clear to me what `row` is or why you want to click it. There may be other ways to handle the action, such as a keystroke. But the first order of troubleshooting is to simplify as much as possible -- your post above is very dense, with no explanation of what's going on (e.g. `set max to the count of menu items of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of group 1
`). Can you strip down your script to isolate the broken `repeat`?

Comment: The code is trying to select the desired directory and "double-click" it so the loop can repeat doing that for each path element until the final destination directory is reached.

Comment: This IS the best I could do to simplify it and still have it usable in context, regretfully.

Comment: what does `log "found " & dir & " at row " & ndx as string` return? Does it display as you expect?

Comment: @pipwerks Yes, it does. For example, it says "Found Macintosh HD at row 5. Right before it fails to dive down into it.

Comment: Thanks for adding detail to your post. What version of iTunes and macOS? I can't get past `click pop up button 1 of group 1` in Sierra with the latest version of iTunes. Also instead of double-click, try CMD-o `keystroke o using {command down}`

Comment: Latest iTunes under El Capitan. Some third-party software I depend on due to disability wants $nnn for Sierra compatible version so I can't do the "free" upgrade.

Comment: @pipwerks Command-O worked! But I'd still like to know the official way it's supposed to be done? That is without using a keyboard shortcut that, to my knowledge is NOT documented ANYWHERE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have refactored your onSwitchDir function to make it work on my machine, and to make it more readable.

I also added a ton of logging to help troubleshoot, feel free to delete.

```
on switchDir(directory, appName, selectDefault, createIt)

    local compname, bootvolume
    set sysInfo to (system info) -- cache value to reduce processing time
    set compname to get computer name of sysInfo
    log "compname: " & compname
    set bootvolume to get boot volume of sysInfo
    log "bootvolume: " & bootvolume
    if directory is equal to "~" then set directory to system attribute ("HOME")
    if directory starts with "~/" then set directory to (system attribute ("HOME")) & text 2 through -1 of (get directory)

    if not checkPathExists(directory) then
        if createIt then
            do shell script ("mkdir -p " & (POSIX path of directory))
        else
            return false
        end if
    end if

    if directory begins with "/" then
        set directory to bootvolume & (get directory)
    end if

    tell application "System Events" to tell (process "iTunes"'s front window)

        -- ensure view is set to expanded view
        try
            click pop up button 1 of group 1
        on error
            key code 81 using {command down} -- expand view
            delay 2 -- esnure it finishes expanding before continuing
        end try

        -- name the item, making the code more readable
        set dropDownMenuBtn to menu 1 of pop up button 1 of group 1

        click dropDownMenuBtn -- selects the drop-down box above the directory listing

        -- Set drop-down menu to go to system's root folder
        -- Variation of solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415994/how-to-get-the-number-of-items-in-a-pop-up-menu-without-opening-it-using-applesc
        tell pop up button 1 of group 1
            if value of it is not equal to compname then
                set menuItemTitles to name of menu items of menu 1
                --check if the menu item exists
                if compname is in menuItemTitles then
                    --menu item exists; click on it
                    click menu item compname of menu 1
                    log "yay! found it! setting menu to item " & compname
                else
                    --the menu item to select doesn't exist; hide the menu
                    log "bummer! " & compname & " doesn't exist"
                    key code 53
                end if
            else
                log "yay! menu already set to " & compname
            end if
        end tell

        -- Make iTunes dialog navigate to root folder
        set thePath to every item of my splitString(directory, "/") -- thePath equals every individual folder in the path's name in order
        log "thePath: " & thePath

        set isFound to false -- so we can exit the repeat loop when needed

        repeat with dir in thePath

            if isFound is false then

                -- set reference to UI element for readability
                set theOutline to outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1

                set max to the (count of rows in theOutline) -- max equals the number of rows in the "directory contents" list box
                log "max for " & dir & ": " & max

                set ndx to 2 -- row 1 is just the column titles

                repeat while ndx ≤ max

                    -- set reference to item for readability
                    set theRow to row ndx of theOutline

                    -- set reference to item for readability                    
                    set theElement to text field 1 of UI element 1 of theRow

                    -- if we have found the appropriate item
                    if the value of theElement is equal to dir as string then

                        -- set focus so we can use keyboard commands on it
                        set value of attribute "AXFocused" of theOutline to true

                        -- select the item in the list
                        select theRow

                        -- set boolean so we can avoid re-running the repeat loop
                        set isFound to true

                        -- exit inner repeat
                        exit repeat

                    else

                        set ndx to (get ndx) + 1

                    end if

                    if ndx > max then error "Never found " & dir

                end repeat

            else

                -- exit outer repeat
                exit repeat

            end if

        end repeat

        -- CMD-o to open the selected directory
        keystroke "o" using {command down}

    end tell

end switchDir

set directory to "/Users/username/Music"

try
    tell application "iTunes" to quit
end try

tell application "System Events"
    key down option
    tell application "iTunes" to activate
    key up option
    repeat until process "iTunes" exists
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
    click process "iTunes"'s window 1's button 2
    my switchDir(directory, "iTunes", false, true)
    delay 0.5
    set libraryName to value of text field "Save As:" of window "New iTunes Library" of process "iTunes"
    delay 0.5
    click process "iTunes"'s window "New iTunes Library"'s button "Save"
end tell
return libraryName
```

Noteworthy changes:

- I changed the handling for exiting the repeat loop; your code had a flaw that would cause the repeat loop to continue exiting even after the `exit repeat` was issued
- I reduced the number of calls to System Info, which speeds up the script
- I created variables as references to items like `menu 1 of pop up button 1 of group 1`, making the script less dense and easier to read
- I changed the method for selecting the drop-down menu item (I find this code simpler to follow)
- I added the `keystroke "o"` command, but placed it AFTER the repeat loop (it wouldn't work while in the loop for some reason)
- I added some error handling to make the script work on my system; for example, if the New Library window was open but in compact mode, the `group 1` reference would cause an error. By ensuring the window is expanded, `group 1` resolves, and I no longer get the error.

Note the outcome of this script is an iTunes warning that it can't create a new library at the requested location. I believe this is because I only have a snippet of your entire script. I imagine you have the other end of the code, which would resolve the issue. If so, you should be able to incorporate these changes into your project without much effort.

Comment: Could you please comment the "key code <number>" lines to indicate what key is actually being sent? Also, is there a list of key codes anywhere?

Comment: escape, it's described in the URL I provided.

Comment: key code 53 is escape as explained here (URL in code above) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415994/how-to-get-the-number-of-items-in-a-pop-up-menu-without-opening-it-using-applesc. The other key code is 81, which is =. There are many resources for key codes online

Comment: With the release of 12.6 even THIS code is broken! It now opens a new "Open" dialog instead of staying in the current dialog as soon aa it finds the first directory of "repeat with dir in thePath"!  Should I post a new question or what?

Comment: The code I posted still works for me with iTunes 12.6. If you can isolate the specific point where the script fails, post it as a new question.